# Двумерные массивы в c#

Tags: c#

1)Как следует объявлять двумерный массив:

```
int[][] array = new int[10][];
```

или

```
int[,] array = new int[10,5];
```

В чём разница?

2)У меня есть двумерный массив array, объявленный как через конструкцию [x,m]. Как я могу узнать высоту и ширину этого массива, то есть x и m?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) 
Первый вариант похож на [массив массивов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2s05feca.aspx), но он не скомпилируется в таком виде, который указан в вопросе.

Второй вариант [стандартный массив](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

2)Например вот так

```
  for (int i = 0; i < array3D.Rank; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(array3D.GetLength(i));;
```

Answer (score 6):

**В дополнение к ответу от @iluxa1810**

Кроме описанных в документации синтаксических различий, стоит учесть еще несколько фактов.

1. Прямоугольные N-мерные массивы хранятся в памяти в виде непрерывного фрагмента и обеспечивают постоянное число элементов в строке по любому измерению. Однако использовать их без реальной необходимости не рекомендуется, т.к. работа с ними плохо оптимизируется не только на уровне CLR, но и на уровне процессора (вымывание кэша и т.д.), что сказывается на конечной производительности. Поэтому если ваша задача не связана с матричными вычислениями или чем-то еще, требующим строго прямоугольных массивов, лучше использовать одномерные, либо массивы массивов.
2. Для любых массивов есть лимит по памяти, для x86 это порядка ~3*10^8 элементов типа `int` (размер int = 4 байта), это связано с ограничением ОС - 2Гб на процесс, разумеется написанная цифра меньше 2Гб, но в памяти процесса даже самого простого консольного приложения будет не только массив.
   Для x64 теоретический предел для ОС - 8Тб на процесс, но на практике это все те же 2Гб, но теперь уже на объект, в данном случае массив. Да и то, это не совсем честные 2Гб, т.к. часть памяти используется под инфраструктуру объекта, поэтому можно считать что ~5*10^8 элементов типа `int`.
   Данные по размерам можно легко проверить простейшим экспериментом. Вроде бы был способ увеличить этот размер, но ссылку дать не могу, а голословно утверждать не хочу.
3. Исходя из первого пункта, мы можем получить довольно высокую производительность, используя одномерный массив одномерных массивов и выстроив алгоритм так, чтобы обеспечить возможность максимальной оптимизации на всех уровнях.
4. Исходя из второго пункта, нетрудно догадаться какое преимущество есть у массива массивов, по сравнению с прямоугольным массивом на платформе х64 - так как для массива массивов не требуется выделение непрерывного фрагмента памяти, то для массива массивом мы получаем по ~2Гб на несущий и каждый вложенный массив, т.е практически ограничены размером ОЗУ. Прямоугольный же будет ограничен все теми же ~2Гб на весь массив.
5. **Никогда так не делайте в реальных проектах!** Эти массивы можно комбинировать. Например запись `int[,][,,][]` вполне валидна и будет нормально принята компилятором, это двумерный массив трехмерных массивов массивов целых чисел. Ну и далее в том же духе. В академических целях вполне можно, и даже нужно хотя бы раз побаловаться, а вот в реальном проекте за такое могут побить, и будут правы.

Вроде ничего существенного не забыл.

Answer (score 3):

Это объявление

```
int[,] array = new int[10,5];
```

действительно объявляет двумерный массив. Выделяется один участок памяти для массива.

Данное объявление, если его правильно записать

```
int[][] array = new int[10][];
```

объявляет массив массивов. Сначала выделяется "внешний массив", а затем для каждого его элемента нужно выделить "внутренний массив". Иди бы вы могли сразу же инициализировать элементы массива в предложении с `new`.

```
    int[][] array =
    {
        new int[] { 1 },
        new int[] { 1, 2 }
        /* и.т.д. */
    };
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

using System;

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] array = new int[10][];

            for ( int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++ )
            {
                array[i] = new int[i + 1];
            }

            for ( int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++ )
            {
                for ( int j = 0; j < array[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    array[i][j] = i * (i + 1) / 2 + j;
                }
            }

            foreach ( var row in array)
            {
                foreach (var x in row) Console.Write("{0} ", x);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
0
1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, второе объявление не откомпилируется.

Comment: @VladD Нельзя доверять тем, кто задает вопросы!:)

Comment: Полагаю, лучше дополнить ответ более подробным описанием прямоугольных массивов.