# C#.Значение скобок в массиве массивов

Tags: c#, массивы

```
int[][,] jaggedArray4 = new int[3][,]
```

Обясните значение каждых скобок при объявлении массива массивов,ведь я понимаю только значение [3],что значит что длина массива - 3.А вот почему первые скобки пустые,а запятые есть в второй и в четвертей?

Comment: Одномерный массив двумерных массивов. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600895/198316) пункт 5, другие части моего ответа и соседние ответы дадут вам полную картину при внимательном чтении.

Answer (score 3):

`int [][,] jaggedArray4` - это одномерный массив, элементами которого являются двумерные массивы типа `int [,]`.

`int [,]` - это ссылочный тип. Это означает, что в переменной типа `int [,]` лежит адрес объекта-массива в памяти, а не сам массив со всеми его элементами. Соответственно, когда вы пишете `new int[3][,]` - вы создаете массив, в котором могут лежать ссылки на двумерные массивы. По умолчанию элементы ни на что не указывают, так что скобки используются пустые - они служат только для обозначения типа, а не для задания размеров.

Реальные внутренние массивы нужно создать дополнительными вызовами, с указанием реального размера. Он может быть разным для каждого из массивов:

```
int[][,] jaggedArray4 = new int[3][,] 
jaggedArray4[0] = new int[5,6];
jaggedArray4[1] = new int[100,100];
jaggedArray4[2] = new int[1,1];
```