# Что означает запятая в объявленном массиве?

Tags: c#

Встретил часть кода:

```
 int[,] Name = ит.д.
```

Вопрос: что обозначает запятая в объявленном массиве?

Comment: что он двумерный

Comment: небольшое уточнение: двумерный и **прямоугольный**, т.е. длина всех строк одинакова

Comment: @rdorn, ну скорее у нас не может быть непрямоугольных двумерных массивов. Если вы имеете ввиду массив [][], то это все же массив массивов, а не двумерный. Вы ведь даже не сможете сразу после инициализации обратиться [a][b], вам придется каждый массив в массиве верхнего уровня перед этим явно создать

Comment: @АндрейNOP по способу взаимодействия с массивом и jagged и прямоугольный являются многомерными массивами. Да, реализация и инициализация у них разные, но сути это не меняет. Есть линейные массивы и многомерные, многомерные бывают прямоугольные, бывают составлены из других массивов. Как-то так и это не противоречит спецификации.

Comment: Вот тут подробнее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600848/198316